# Set metadata while using s3cmd to upload static website to Amazon S3

Tags: web, amazon-s3

I'm generating a static webpage from markdown using Pelican. Then, I upload the output to S3 using s3cmd:

```
s3cmd sync -rr --delete-removed output/ s3://mybucket/
```

Unfortunately, the metadata for the css files are set wrong, I've to set them manualy to "text/css". Is there a way to make s3cmd to set them (and maybe other filetypes to) to a correct value? Or if not, is there a alternative to s3cmd which runs on Linux and MacOS X?

Comment: Which version of s3cmd are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the mime-type of a file while uploading to s3 by using the -m switch

```
s3cmd -m text/css ./file.css s3:/path/to/bucket
```

Additionally, what I do, is compress it with gzip first, then upload to s3, but you have to set the content encoding as well. Note that Chrome and Safari sometimes don't like the .gz extension so i use .jgz.

```
gzip file.css -9 -c > file.css.jgz
s3cmd -m text/css ./file.css s3:/path/to/bucket
s3cmd -m text/css --add-header "Content-Encoding:gzip" ./file.css.jgz s3:/path/to/bucket
```

Also note that in the html file that links to this css, you should check that the browser can handle a gzip. Here is a sample in php:

```
<?php
  $css = "$PATH_TO_S3_BUCKET/file.css";
  if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) 
      $css .= '.jgz'; 

  echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='$css'/>";
?>
```